# Xamarin ZXing scanner write logic after scan is complete

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am working on a C# Xamarin project. In the project, I have used the  ZXing.Net.Mobile class library in order to implement a QR code Scanner.

After the user scans the QR code, a url is revealed. Which is used to send data to a webservice. My issue is: midway during the execution of the method **connectToBackend** the thread BeginInvokeOnMainThread expires. As a consequence the execution of **connectToBackend** never finishes. I need help about how to handle this thread scenario so that I can process my server request.

```
public void ShowScannerPage() {

        ZXingScannerPage scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();

        scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) => {

            // stop scanning
            scanPage.IsScanning = false;

            ZXing.BarcodeFormat barcodeFormat = result.BarcodeFormat;
            string type = barcodeFormat.ToString();


    // This thread finishes before the method, connectToBackend, inside has time to finish   
            Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {

                 //_pageService.PopAsync();
                _pageService.PopAsync();


                App.UserDialogManager.ShowAlertDialog("The Barcode type is : " + type, "The text is : " + result.Text, " OK");

        // problem here 
                connectToBackend(result.Text);
            });

    // If I put connectToBackend here there is still a problem

        };

        _pageService.PushAsync(scanPage);

    }
```

To provide more information, I am using the MVVM approach. I have a page and when the users clicks on the scan button, the method ShowScannerPage opens up the scanner view on their mobile using the ZXing.Net Mobile library. I have a pasted my class below.

```
public class WorkoutViewModel {

    public ICommand ScanCommand { get; private set; }

    public readonly IPageService _pageService;

    public WorkoutViewModel(IPageService pageService) {

        this._pageService = pageService;

        ScanCommand = new Command(ShowScannerPage);

    }

    public void ShowScannerPage() {

        ZXingScannerPage scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();

        scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) => {

            // stop scanning
            scanPage.IsScanning = false;

            ZXing.BarcodeFormat barcodeFormat = result.BarcodeFormat;
            string type = barcodeFormat.ToString();


    // This thread finishes before the method, connectToBackend, inside has time to finish   
            Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {

                 //_pageService.PopAsync();
                _pageService.PopAsync();


                App.UserDialogManager.ShowAlertDialog("The Barcode type is : " + type, "The text is : " + result.Text, " OK");

        // problem here 
                connectToBackend(result.Text);
            });

    // If I put connectToBackend here there is still a problem

        };

        _pageService.PushAsync(scanPage);

    }

    public async void connectToBackend(String nodes) {

        // call api ...

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are calling an async function (`async void connectToBackend(String nodes)`) without the `await` keyword.

I think you can define "`async`" the event `scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) => {` so you can `async` the `connectToBackend` function.

I think `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` is not necessary